# How to send multiple input to controller spring mvc with jquery Ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller

I want to send a multipart to a controller spring but I can not get the result and no error is reported ?

```
/*javascript on submit*/
var formData = new FormData();
for(var i = 0; i < nPhotos; i++) {
    formData.append('files', multiResult[i]);
}
$.ajax({
    url: serverContext + "new/save",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {},
    error: function (data) {},
    complete: function (data) {}
});

/*controller*/
@RequestMapping(value = "/new/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public GenericResponse saveNewpost(@Valid final PostForm postForm, 
    @RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile[] files,
    @AuthenticationPrincipal final User user) {

    System.out.println(postForm); /* all attr presents */
    System.out.println(files.length); /* but files.length always equal 0  */

    return new GenericResponse("success");
}
```

Can someone help me? thank you

Comment: Can you post HTML code of your input element?

Comment: Also, try something like this, and let me know the output
```for(var i = 0; i < nPhotos; i++) {
    formData.append('files[' + i + ']', multiResult[i]);
}```
Put some log in your success and error section of ajax.

Comment: The object multiResult[i] it a URL construct with URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);

Comment: The solution it: formData.append('files', new File(multiResult[i], "file" + i));